# Exec and query to database through ORM

Tags: python

**Python 3.5.2**

This is Django'd ORM syntax. But I think, the question is about Python.

I have prepared rather a huge string with a chain of ORM queries. ORM is a wrapper for accessing data base.

The plan was to execute it via 'exec'.

Well, not working. Whereas the string itself looks correct.

Below there is a model. Well, just plain code works well. And with exec it doesn't.

Could you help me understand why it is like that? And how to make it work.

```
exec('Frame.objects.filter(title__icontains = "Michael")')

   => Result = None


Frame.objects.filter(title__icontains = "Michael")

   => Result = <QuerySet [<Frame: 1: Michael's news>]>
```

If it is not just a question about Python, pardon for that.

Comment: `The plan was to execute it via 'exec'.` You can't. And if you could, you probably shouldnt'

Comment: But why it is impossible? This seems to be just a python code.

Comment: Please dont. Why would you do such thing?

Comment: The alternative I can think of is raw sql. This is a complicated request. I decided to compose it as a string. It seemed simpler.

Comment: but why do you need to run it via `exec`? Just run the Python code directly

Comment: Well, this is a complicated request to the database. I need to compose it beforehand. But I don't know how. That is why I have composed a string first.

Comment: check Django Raw Queries: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries, so you can do something like: `Frame.objects.raw("select * from here_goes_your_complicated_query")`